# Laravel > route, filter URL against database

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm trying to build the new version of our site with the Laravel 5 framework.

The problem is, we have now the following site structure (and this may not be changed):

- domain.com/[productname] <- dynamic
- domain.com/[categoryname] <- dynamic
- domain.com/some-static-page1
- domain.com/some-static-page2
- ....

In our database, we have a list of different product names and different categories.

I want to route the [productname] to a productController and the [categoryname] to the categoryController. But therefor, i need query our database with each request to see if the URL parameter is either a product or a category.

Any ideas to get me on right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be the best way to do it:

Route:

```
Route::get('/cat={name}', 'CatagoryController@cataFind');
Route::get('/prod={name}', 'ProductController@prodfind');
```

Controller:

```
public function cataFind($name){
 //get all the rows with that cata
 $catas = Product::where('cata', $name)->get();
 return view('cata')->with('catas', $catas);
}

public function prodFind($name){
 //get all the rows with that prod name
 $prod = Product::where('name', $name)->get();
 return view('prod')->with('prod', $prod);
}
```

If you need any exsplnation on what's going on,, then just comment and I'll update the post. But this is the path you should be taking I should of thought!

Comment: Thanks for your input Ashley! Unfortunately i can't get it working like that.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ashley! Unfortunately i can't get it working like that. It doesn't catch any routes like that :( By example uri: domain.com/books doensn't tigger a search in the category nor in the product contoller. It should first try to query "book" in the the category mysql table using the CatagoryController. If that doens't return any records, it should query the products mysql table to find a match. If no matches are found, it has to go to a next route found in the routes.php file.